# woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart not working

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to move `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` section under the tab section. For this, I have done below coding

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'filter_grouped_cart');
function filter_grouped_cart(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

But when I have placed `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` on the tab it's showing nothing.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab');

function woo_new_product_tab($tabs) {
    $tabs['related_products'] = array(
        'title' => __('Models', 'woocommerce'),
        'priority' => 50,
        'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
}
```

Can anyone please help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'filter_grouped_cart', 0);
function filter_grouped_cart(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    // add it to new action hook... this will complete the "move"
    add_action( 'woo_new_product_tab_content', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', );
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab');
function woo_new_product_tab($tabs) {
    $tabs['related_products'] = array(
        'title' => __('Models', 'woocommerce'),
        'priority' => 50,
        'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    // run our own action hook
    do_action( 'woo_new_product_tab_content' );
}
```

An action hook is a point where your function will run. See attached image:
[image]
When you remove an action hooked to `woocommerce_single_product_summary`, that works, but adding it again on the same hook will not move it somewhere. Because that point is still there. Moving means you have to remove it from a that hook, then add it to another hook. It's like removing it on point A and placing it on point B.

Comment: @Soumyadip added some explanations ;)